# PTIJ: Torah is most important

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The pasuk says והעיר שושן צהלה ושמחה. This was before the war happened yet, so how could they rejoice, they didn't know they were going to win?

The answer must be they were confident in the (צהל(ה and the סם חיה the Torah which is compared to סם חיים-- the שׂ & ס are interchangeable. They were confident in their torah and that they would be able to fight the war.

The question is, Torah and tefilah have a lot more to do with success in battle than fighting. So why does the pasuk say the צהל first, if they put their trust in Hashem in the zechus of Torah?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from man’s point of view, like the pasuk

> יי מלך יי מלך יי ימלוך לעולם ועד- g-d is king, He was king, and He will be king, forever and ever.

First comes what man most understand, the present, then less understand, the past, and then least understand, the future.
So too here. First comes what man most understands, an army, then what man least understands, tefilah.